# Django sessions save only one object

Tags: django, session

I am building online store and want to use sessions to allow anonymous users to add items to carts before logging in .
trying to save the added items in session as a list but it saves only last object added to list

```
def cart(request):
    user_id = request.user.id
    cart_items =Cart.objects.all().filter(user_id=user_id, is_ordered=False)


    ids = request.session.get('cart_id')

    if ids:
        for cart_id in ids:
            if request.user.is_authenticated:
                cart = Cart.objects.get(id=cart_id)
                if cart:
                    cart.user = request.user
                    cart.save()


    # get total prices
    prices = []
    for item in cart_items:
        prices.append(item.item.price * item.qty)
    total_price = sum(prices)
    context = {
        'items': cart_items,
        'total_price': total_price
    }
    request.session['prices'] = prices


    return render(request, 'cart.html', context)
```

def add_to_cart(request):

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    item = Item.objects.get(pk=request.POST['item_id'])
    cart = Cart.objects.filter(
    user=request.user, item=item, is_ordered=False).first()
    if cart:
        cart.qty += 1
        cart.save()
        messages.success(request, 'item added to cart!')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
    else:
        cart = Cart(user=request.user, item=item)
        cart.save()
        messages.success(request, 'item added to cart!')
else:
    carts_ids = []
    session_cart = request.session.get('cart_id')
    item = Item.objects.get(pk=request.POST['item_id'])
    if session_cart :  
        for cart in session_cart:
            carts = Cart.objects.all().filter(id=cart, item=item)
            if carts:
                cart = carts.filter(item=item)[0]
                print(cart.qty)
                cart.qty += 1
                cart.save()
            else:
                print('new cart')
                new_cart = Cart(item=item)
                new_cart.save()
                carts_ids.append(new_cart.id)
                request.session['cart_id'] = carts_ids
    else:
        print('new session')
        new_cart = Cart(item=item)
        new_cart.save()
        carts_ids.append(new_cart.id)
        request.session['cart_id'] = carts_ids

return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

here are my [models.py](https://github.com/ma7aziz/dummypharmacy/blob/master/cart/models.py)
and the full code on github i am only working now on these to views (cart and add_to_cart)

appriciate any help to get over this and to simplify my code :)

Answer (score 0):

The idea would be that you save the whole cart in sessions so that you can reload it when the same user comes back to your website. So your code should look like this:

```
prices = []
itemlist=[]
for item in cart_items:
    prices.append(item.item.price * item.qty)
    itemlist.append(item.item, item.qty)
total_price = sum(prices)
context = {
    'items': cart_items,
    'total_price': total_price
}
request.session['items'] = itemlist
```

End then you also will need to read out this list.

Comment: on my db i'm creating a new cart for every item (i know it sucks) ,
 i need to keep a list of these carts ids in session so i can save these carts to the user when he logs in , it's working but only for on cart(item) 
you can see my models here 
https://github.com/ma7aziz/dummypharmacy/blob/master/cart/models.py